# Loop from textbox and grdilookup controls - vb.net

Tags: vb.net

First i use VB.NET . 
How can I write this code on easy way and more simple way. I want to loop from textbox controls and gridGookUp controls to empty any value. Here is my code:

```
    txtBankName.Text = String.Empty
    txtPaymentCurrencyTypeCode.Text = ""
    txtPaymentCurrencyTypeName.Text = ""
    txtPreviouseBalance.EditValue = 0.0
    txtAccountReceivable.EditValue = 0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through controls in your form or userControl to initialize all

for each c in Me.controls

if typeof(c) is TextBox then c.text=string.empty

if typeof(c) is GridLookUp then c.editvalue=0.0

next